# Google Drive Rest API : How to get all Modifying Users of a specific Revision

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to get the list of all modifying users of a Specific revision. Because I want track changes made by each user to a specific file/revision.

Currently the api provides only the `lastModifyingUser`. But in the UI it shows the details of a revision under the `show revision history`

1. Is it possible to get all modifying users of a specific revision?
2. OR is there any way I can track every changes made by any users in a specific file/revision?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate the Drive API currently doesn't provide that level of detail, as shown in the UI. Please file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Drive) so we can track that request.

A partial solution is to use the [Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/). It provides more fine-grained information on which users edited a document, but unfortunately there is no easy way to correlate those activities to revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are talking about Google documents (Docs and Sheets).  As far as I know, there is no API that will provide you with the revision history of a Google Docs or Sheets file.