# How to get all Modifying Users of a specific Revision

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Follow up on [Google Drive Rest API : How to get all Modifying Users of a specific Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383004/google-drive-rest-api-how-to-get-all-modifying-users-of-a-specific-revision)

It has been approximately 3 years, so I am not sure what the status is, but I thought I would ask again on the status.

I see that Google Drive API @ https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get

should actually do exactly what has been asked here, but when I make a call to the API it returns `null` for `LastModifyingUser`

I am not sure if this is a work in progress API or I am doing something wrong, so any help would be appreciated. 
Just to provide some reference, I am posting some basic code that is an addition to what can be found here... https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/go

```
revision, err := srv.Revisions.Get(fileId, revisionId).Do() //fieldId and revisionId are fatched using proper calls

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve revision: %v", err)
}
fmt.Println("Revision:")
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", revision.LastModifyingUser)
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of `lastModifyingUser` from `Revisions.Get()` using Drive API v3.

If my understanding is correct, how about adding the fields? At the default, the fields are `id,mimeType,modifiedTime`. So when you want to retrieve only values of `lastModifyingUser`, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
revision, err := srv.Revisions.Get(fileId, revisionId).Do()
```

#### To:

```
revision, err := srv.Revisions.Get(fileID, revisionID).Fields("lastModifyingUser").Do()
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it is supposes that when you run your current script, no error occurs.
- If you want to add `lastModifyingUser` to the default values of `id,mimeType,modifiedTime`, please set the fields to `id,mimeType,modifiedTime,lastModifyingUser`.

#### Reference:

- [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.